# htaccess rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been tring for some time now with htaccess to rewrite this url

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php?id=whatever
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/?id=whatever
```

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Why you trying to rewrite an ugly URL into a "less ugly" only instead of use the www.domain.com/whatever format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ folder/file.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ folder/file.php [QSA]
```

look for the exact syntax urself ... also notice the QSA flag ... actually it redirects the query string from called url to actual url ... also you can not match the part after '?' ie the query string in the regex ...